# Adding several Shared Access Policies in ARM template creates only one

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-resource-manager

I am deploying a Event Hub with ARM template, and with that I want several Shared Access Policies added to give access to different clients. The problem is that deploying the ARM template only creates one(or sometimes two) of the several defined policies. The rest is not created even though they are defined in the same way. If I redeploy the template one of the restoring policies is added.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent this kind of behavior and other errors, add a "Depend" from a Shared Access Policy to another. This will make sure the Shared Access Policies are created 1 by 1 instead of parallel.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for but wasn't able to find.